# insert widget in dojo/dnd source

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo/dnd to drag and drop and rearrange an array of widgets

Current I am inserting nodes to drag and drop source using following code

```
dragDropSourceNode.insertNodes(false, [widget.domNode]);
```

Instead of inserting the domNode can I insert the **widget** itself.

**My widgets have widget_number attribute(property)** assigned to it and I have an array of widgets.

Every Time there is a drag and drop, I need to change the widget_number. Also i need to rearrange the array.

But since I am sending the domNode inside, there is no way I can change the widget itself or call any function of the widget.

Is there a way to link both of them?

Comment: One solution I can thing of is :

1) From domNode get widget_id and do registry.byId to get the widget and everytime there is a drag drop event, recreate the array based on the updated nodes in drag drop object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From domNode get widget_id and do registry.byId to get the widget and everytime there is a drag drop event, recreate the array based on the updated nodes in drag drop object.